# Using http client to send header and content via post

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, http, xamarin

I'm making a really simple call to an API to receive some data. I need to send headers to get authorized also I need to send some content on the body. This is what I came up with :

```
public async Task<List<LoremIpsum>> LoremIpsumJson()
    {
        LoremIpsum1 data = null;
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            //now lets add headers . 1.method, 2.token
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Method", "LoremIpsumExample");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", "sometoken");
            HttpContent content = new StringContent("{\"Name\":\"John\",\"Surname\":\"Doe\",\"Example\":\"SomeNumber\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            // ==edit==
             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = await client.PostAsync("www.theUrlToTheApi", content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueueInfo>(json);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        return data.data;
        Debug.WriteLine(data.data);
    }
```

The app breaks after `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` because the request obviously is not successful. 
I think I'm really missing something really simple here. How can I do this call?
The error is

> StatusCode: 406, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Acceptable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone coming here to find a solution. 
HttpContent cannot take a header much o less a content-type. There was a typo on adding the content-type which was supposed to be added in HttpClient in this way:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons for this not working. For instance: `keyvalues.ToString()` is most likely not putting in the value you want. Seems like you might need to serialize to json rather than just calling `.ToString()`.

Use a tool like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) first and get it working there so you have a working example then try and recreate in C#. It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I already made it work with postman. The thing that it seems I can't do that in code. I also tried this line `HttpContent content = new StringContent("{\"Name\":\"John\",\"Surname\":\"Doe\",\"Example\":\"SomeNumber\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");` which I saw like a solution somewhere scrolling in SO. @pmcilreavy

Comment: @John Maybe include screenshot of your working postman request in your question. That might help SO arrive at an answer..

Comment: If you'd want to do something like this, how would you do it?! That is: Send some headers, and also some content in the body with post request.   Also in the response code I noticed I had a `Content-Type: text/html` in the headers , when I specified `application/json`. Any idea why is this happening? @pmcilreavy

Comment: @John You might want to look at the RestSharp library, it makes this stuff a lot easier. http://restsharp.org/